# Can conjugate subgroups be like this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G,H,K be three different subgroups of some group and are conjugate with one another. Will the situations below ever happen?

A. The intersection of G and H is a non trivial group but the intersection of H and K is trivial. More generally, can the intersection of each two of them be of different orders?

B. The intersection of G and H, H and K, K and G are non trivial groups of the same order but are different with one another.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The answer to A is yes. Consider the symmetric group $S_{10}$. Let $G = \{e, (1\ 2), (3\ 4), (1\ 2)(3\ 4)\}$, and $H = \{e, (1\ 2), (5\ 6), (1\ 2)(5\ 6)\}$, and $K = \{e, (7\ 8), (9\ 10), (7\ 8)(9\ 10)\}$. It's easy to check that these subgroups are all conjugate, e.g. to go from $G$ to $H$, conjugate by any element which takes $1 \mapsto 7$, $2 \mapsto 8$, $5 \mapsto 9$, and $6 \mapsto 10$. We have $G \cap H = \{e, (1\ 2)\}$, but $K$ has trivial intersection with $G$ and $H$.

Comment: If you use $G$ and $H$ as above, and change $K$ to $\{e, (3\ 4), (5\ 6), (3\ 4)(5\ 6)\}$, then you get an example satisfying B.

Comment: @Bungo Really appreciate that! May I ask how did you come up with these examples? It takes me a long time and I get nothing.

Comment: I already knew that the answer to both questions is "yes", so it was just a matter of finding concrete examples.The symmetric group is convenient because it's easy to verify conjugacy: two elements are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle structure, and therefore two subgroups are conjugate if and only if they are generated by elements with the same cycle structure.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you very much! That helps a lot!